# Sniffing wifi using libpcap in monitor mode

Tags: wifi, pcap, libpcap

**Problem Statement**

Calling `pcap_activate()` results in `PCAP_ERR_RFMON_NOTSUP` error, i.e. RF monitor mode is not supported.

**Context**

I'm writing small C program whose job is to listen on my laptop's wifi card in monitor mode. The laptop is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I ran `airmon-ng start wlan0` command after which mon0 interface appeared. Following shows output of iwconfig command after running the airmon command:

```
$ iwconfig
mon0      IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SKY88F48"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 7C:4C:A5:3B:33:59   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:415   Missed beacon:0
```

**Question**

In my program, I create network handle on device mon0 using `pcap_create()`. Then I set snapshot length and promiscuous mode successfully.

When I check if rfmon can be set, using `pcap_can_set_rfmon()` method, it returns positive. Then I set rfmon using  `pcap_set_rfmon()` method which goes through successfully. I also set timeout. Finally when I call `pcap_activate()` it returns error `PCAP_ERR_RFMON_NOTSUP`, i.e. RF monitor mode not supported. I'm running my program as root.

One thing to note is that I installed wireshark and started listening on mon0 which successfully captured all the traffic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to set rfmon mode on mon0 - it's inherently in monitor mode.  Just capture on it; that's what you did with Wireshark.

For various reasons having to do with

1. libnl having multiple incompatible versions, so choosing the right version with which to build libpcap is, apparently, a pain for distribution builders;
2. choosing a version different from the one used by an application that uses both libnl and libpcap causing horrible problems due to the aforementioned incompatibilities;

the libpcap rfmon mode code for Linux that works best for most devices, which uses libnl  (essentially, it creates a new monN interface, duplicating what airmon-ng does, opens that interface for capturing, and deletes it when the capture is finished), is *not* enabled in many Linux distributions because libpcap is configured *not* to use libnl.

Therefore, it doesn't work well on Linux.

Writing code for libpcap to directly use netlink sockets, rather than go through libnl, is on my to-do list, but it is, unfortunately, behind a number of other issues on that list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set a device in monitor mode using the pcap library in C, you can use the following commands (see [pcap manpage](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html)):

## SYNOPSIS

```
#include <pcap/pcap.h>

int pcap_can_set_rfmon(pcap_t *p);
```

## DESCRIPTION

`pcap_can_set_rfmon()` checks whether monitor mode could be set on a capture handle when the handle is activated.

---

## SYNOPSIS

```
#include <pcap/pcap.h>

int pcap_set_rfmon(pcap_t *p, int rfmon);
```

## DESCRIPTION

`pcap_set_rfmon()` sets whether monitor mode should be set on a capture handle when the handle is activated. If rfmon is non-zero, monitor mode will be set, otherwise it will not be set.